# Simulate moving mouse outside of webpage area using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to test the exit intent form on this page: https://biotrust.com/pages/ageless-multi-collagen-protein-powder-tm-vl

When the mouse pointer is moved outside of the web page area a popup window appears. I then need to click a link on the pop up.

How can I move the mouse outside of the web page area to trigger the popup? Note, the mouse pointer doesn't need to leave the window entirely, it could go up to the address bar/refresh button area (really any where but the web page area). I tried the actions move_by_offset method but its not consistently working.

I'm selenium in python.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

driver window_handle may be  te technique to switch to the pop up window and then perform desired action..

```
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    if handle == 'your window title':
        print(handle)
        login_page = handle
        break

driver.switch_to.window('your window title)
```

## if you already know the title of window you can switch by least line

Comment: Thanks, but i need to trigger the pop up first before i am able to continue to click actions. How would i do that?

Comment: when I clicked the link given in your post there is a popup which has text like - Wait! By clicking out of this page you'l... where you want to click ..??

Comment: My test will be to click the Read Transcript link. thanks